# Prev and Next Button On a one page Website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a one page website and I'm using [this template](https://codepen.io/Danstan/pen/zKQxGP).

I want the next button to only show when I'm scrolling down and the prev button to hide untill I reach the last slide. Once I'm on the last slide the prev arrow should show and once I click on it, it is suppose to scroll to the  first slide at the top and not the next slide after the last one.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cd-vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="#0" class="cd-prev inactive">Next</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0" class="cd-next">Prev</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I Have tried so many times to achieve this but nothing has come out

I have manged to change this on the main jquery

`( sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible').is(':last-of-type') ) ? nextArrow.addClass('inactive') : nextArrow.removeClass('inactive'); ( sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible').is(':last-of-type') ) ? prevArrow.removeClass('inactive') : prevArrow.addClass('inactive');`

Check out the edited version [HERE](https://codepen.io/Danstan/pen/zKQxqp). Now I need the prev arrow to scroll to the first slide(Slide 1) and not the way it is doing now

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question. It may not work, but it helps us to see the context your code is running under

Comment: I have manged to change this on the main jquery

( sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible').is(':last-of-type')  ) ? nextArrow.addClass('inactive') : nextArrow.removeClass('inactive');
( sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible').is(':last-of-type') ) ? prevArrow.removeClass('inactive') : prevArrow.addClass('inactive');

Check out the edited version [HERE](https://codepen.io/Danstan/pen/zKQxqp). Now I need the prev arrow to scroll to the first slide(Slide 1) and not the way it is doing now

Comment: Offtopic: if your "prev" button does not go to the "previous" item, then it should not be captioned "prev" - it should be captioned "top"

Comment: And that's what i'm trying to achieve for me as long as it is scrolling to the top i have no issue

Comment: Let me know if I understand. You want to change the functionality of the prev button so it will not slide to the prev slide but the top? (Also, show/ hide the buttons regards to the current slide)

Comment: @MoshFeu yes I want to change to changed the functionality